# How to recode first two digits SPSS

Tags: spss, recode

I have two variables, A and B, that both use a 5-digit code starting with 50.  So variable A might be 50123 to designate orange and B might be 50123 to designate apple.  The codes were originally constructed to be concatenated together to create a single hierarchy code.  I now need to consider them independently and must be able to distinguish between a code for variable A and variable B.

Bottom line is I want to recode variable A items from 50123 to 60123 and variable B items from 50123 to 70123.  What's the best way to do this in SPSS without having to manually enter items either in syntax or the recode dialog box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If variables A and B are numbers, you could try

```
compute A=A+10000.
compute B=B+20000.
```

If they are strings, this should work:

```
compute A=concat("6", char.substr(A,2,5)).
compute B=concat("7", char.substr(B,2,5)).
```